# GCM only works 1 time after send heartbeat

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am facing a problem with using GCM as chat. User A can receive as many GCM as possible, if he does not reply. However, when User A tries to reply, after a few times both party sending message to each other, they will stop receiving GCM. I tried to look around and see a solution when sending Heartbeat every 2 minutes. However, after sending the Heartbeat, I will only receive GCM 1 more time until the next heartbeat is sent.

Currently, to fix this, I have to change network state (change to mobile network, or turn off then turn on Wifi again). How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you receive any errors,  like `tooManyMessages`?

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for the reply. Where do I get this message? From Android or the Server? I didn't notice, I will check again.

Comment: In android. After sending an upstream message, googleCloudMessaging API will tell you if it is successful or has any errors.

Comment: Could you include a code snippet that you are using to send the upstream message?

Comment: Hi Arthur and Ali, my server used an Ruby Gem called Houston to send GCM. When a user click "send" button, I call to the sending message API then my server will send the GCM message. It always work well if only user A sends message to user B, but when B tries to reply, it will be broken after a few times.